# Mostrar datos de Firebase en una tabla en HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

That's my firebase db

[image]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}

table {
    border-spacing: 5px;
}

</style>

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.2/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyDr2Im1C1lQvrxuQocW4ul69MKwRfc5g6g",
    authDomain: "denuncias-app.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://denuncias-app.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "denuncias-app",
    storageBucket: "denuncias-app.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "885651585540"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>

<head>
    <title>Denuncias Municipales ASDE</title>
    </head>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr id="tr">
    <th>Tipo de la Denuncia:</th>
    <th>Dirección:</th> 
    <th>Descripción:</th>
    <th>Correo:</th>
    <th>Creda por:</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Lat - Long</th>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <tr>
  </tr>
</table>

<script>
//firebase script should be here


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola @HommyDeJesus ¿Cuál es el problema que estas teniendo? Deberías explicar un poco más  tu problema, y si estás teniendo algún error mostrarlo para que te podamos ayudar. Además te invito a que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)  de SO para ver cómo funciona el sitio y cómo preguntar.

Comment: Ya lo actualicé, ¿Lo puedes entender? En verdad necesito terminar esto. Lo que quiero puede parecer simple pero en verdad para mi no lo es, solo quiero insertar esos datos que ves en la imagen de la firebase db en una tabla que creé @Joacer

Comment: Desgraciadamente no he trabajado nunca con Firebase y no te puedo ayudar en este aspecto, por otra parte te quería ayudar a mejorar la calidad de la pregunta para que no la cierren y te pueda ayudar más gente. Te agradecería que cambiaras el título y el contenido que está en inglés y lo pongas en español, ya que puede ser cerrada por este motivo y ampliaras la descripción del problema

Comment: @Joacer Ahh, entiendo. Gracias de todos modos.

Comment: Te faltó traducir la primera oración, si puedes edítala nuevamente y arregla eso... (perdón, yo tampoco te puedo ayudar, nunca he trabajado con Firebase) Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

después de tanto  romperme la cabeza, mezcle varios métodos de varios foros

Tengo mi base en Firebase

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi tabla html:

```js
function busca_user() {    
   
   


var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("users");
     
var table = document.getElementById("tabla");
    
//limpia la tabla
table.innerHTML = "";
 
 //con esta función recorre todos los datos almacenados en FB ordenados por mi child(tipo)
    
ref.orderByChild("tipo").on("child_added", function(snapshot){
//repite el proceso como cuantas referencias encuentre y los asigna a la lista "d"
     
  var d = snapshot.val();        
        
  {
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  
  // asigna a las celdas el valir del Child especificado
  cell1.innerHTML = d.email;
  cell2.innerHTML = d.tipo;
  }
 
        
});
 
}
```

```html
 <table>
     <thead>
            <tr>
                <th  style="color:white">email</th>
                <th  style="color:white">tipo</th>                                    
             </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="tabla">                                
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]